# Unable to select depart date in https://spicejet.com through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to select a "Depart date" as of 31st october 2018 from the calender https://spicejet.com/ But I am getting error "unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (832, 242). Other element would receive the click: ..." Please help me out. Here is my code getting such exception:

```
public class bookflight extends Thread {

    UtilityMethods utilObj= new UtilityMethods();
    @Test
    public void SighnUp() throws IOException
    {
        utilObj.getdriver().get("https://spicejet.com");
        utilObj.getdriver().manage().window().maximize();

        utilObj.getdriver().findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")).click();
        utilObj.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Guwahati (GAU)')]")).click();
        utilObj.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Goa (GOI)')]")).click();
        utilObj.getdriver().findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-trigger")).click();
        utilObj.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-first'])/parent:://table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']following-sibling::./a/contains(text(),'31')")).click();           
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rohan Kerry your XPath is wrong

Comment: //*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/a this xpath return you all the date just iterate the loop and find exect match which you want to select.

Comment: have you tried making use of javascript executor to click that element? (Provided XPath is valid)

Comment: try to check my updated post which resolves problem related to your question to `click on the next date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select **From** (e.g. **Guwahati(GAU)**), **To** (e.g. **Goa(GOI)**) destination and **DEPART DATE** as **31/10** within the *url* `https://spicejet.com/` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class spicejet_login {

      public static void main(String[] args) {


          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://spicejet.com");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']"))).click();
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTNR']//table[@id='citydropdown']//li/a[@value='GAU']")).click();
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//table[@id='citydropdown']//li/a[@value='GOI']")).click();
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr//a[contains(@class,'ui-state-default') and contains(.,'31')]"))).click();
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: spicejet_depart_date_31oct2018.png]

Comment: I have selected the places already, I am facing issue with selecting the "Depart Date"

Comment: @RohnKerry Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: I tried, It is getting error-  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//table[@id='citydropdown']//li/a[@value='GOI']"}

Comment: I am just stuck at the "depart date", I have to get the date of 31st october. Rest of my code is working fine.

Comment: @RohnKerry I think you have commented previously that **I have selected the places already, I am facing issue with selecting the "Depart Date"**. So `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//table[@id='citydropdown']//li/a[@value='GOI']"}` shouldn't be an issue anyway. What is your exact question? Where are you stuct exactly?

Comment: I am struck at selecting date from Calender. Lets suppose If I have to select Depart Date 31st october from Calender, So I am unable to click at "31" from calender.

Comment: @RohnKerry Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of different factors which results into this exception,
i like to suggest you to try putting some wait.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(utilObj.getdriver(), 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")));
```

then try clicking element,

```
utilObj.getdriver().findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click on element by Action class, based on Exception type:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(WebElement to click).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer to click next date.

```
//div[contains(@class, 'ui-datepicker-group-first')]//td[@data-month='9' and @data-year='2018']/a[.=31]
```

You can modify the above `XPATH` to select date based on `YEAR/MONTH/DATE`. for more [`XPath creation go-through my answers`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5081877+%5Bxpath%5D).

```javascript
var path ="//div[contains(@class, 'ui-datepicker-group-first')]//td[@data-month='9' and @data-year='2018']/a[.=31]";
var elem = document.evaluate(path, window.document, null, 9, null ).singleNodeValue;
console.log( elem );
elem.click();
```

---

When you enter `FROM` and `TO` data, then `DEPART DATE` field get auto selected. So, just you need to select the first data using javascript.

```
FROM « //div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTNR']//a[@text='Guwahati (GAU)']
TO « //div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//a[@text='Goa (GOI)']
DEPART DATE «
//div[contains(@class, 'ui-datepicker-group-first')]//a[contains(@class, 'ui-state-active')]
```

sample test program.

```java
import io.github.yash777.driver.Browser;
import io.github.yash777.driver.Drivers;
import io.github.yash777.driver.WebDriverException;

public class SpiceJET {
    static WebDriver driver;
    static WebDriverWait explicitWait;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws WebDriverException, IOException {
        test();
    }
    public static void test() throws WebDriverException, IOException {
        Drivers drivers = new Drivers();
        String driverPath = drivers.getDriverPath(Browser.CHROME, 63, "");

        System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, driverPath);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        driver = new ChromeDriver( capabilities );
        explicitWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        //Maximize browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //Go to URL which you want to navigate
        driver.get("https://spicejet.com/");

        clickElement("//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT'][1]");
        clickElement("//div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTNR']//a[@text='Guwahati (GAU)']");
        clickElement("//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTXT'][1]");
        clickElement("//div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//a[@text='Goa (GOI)']");

        clickUsingJavaScript("//div[contains(@class, 'ui-datepicker-group-first')]//a[contains(@class, 'ui-state-active')]");
    }
}
```

```java
public static void clickElement(String locator) {
    By findBy = By.xpath( locator );
    WebElement element = explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable( findBy ));
    element.click();
}

public static void clickUsingJavaScript( String locator ) {
    StringBuffer click = new StringBuffer();
    click.append("var elem = document.evaluate(\""+locator+"\", window.document, null, 9, null ).singleNodeValue;");
    click.append("elem.click();");
    System.out.println("JavaScript Click.");
    jse.executeScript( click.toString() );
}
```

> For Automatic management of Selenium Driver Executable’s in run-time for Java use [**`SeleniumWebDrivers`**](https://yash-777.github.io/SeleniumWebDrivers/)

**NOTE:** If you are selecting `DEPART DATE` which got auto selected then selenium throws exception

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:
>   Element `<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="ctl00_mainContent_view_date2" class="custom_date_pic required home-date-pick">`
>   is not clickable at point (784, 241). Other element would receive the click: `<span class="ui-datepicker-month">...</span>`

Comment: Can be solved in a more easy way like this: new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr//a[contains(@class,'ui-state-default') and contains(.,'31')]"))).click();

Comment: @RohnKerry we may solve in many ways, that is fine. It resolves your problem or not related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code is helpful and handle departure and return date

```js
public class SpicejetDropdowns1 { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{ System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\ChromeDriver\\ChromeDriver2.46\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();   
driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_mainContent_rbtnl_Trip_1")).click();
// OriginStation
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[value='DEL']")).click();     
// Destination
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTXT']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@value='HYD'])[2]")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_view_date1']")).click();
if(driver.findElement(By.id("Div1")).getAttribute("style").contains("1"))
{
System.out.println("its enabled");
Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
else
{
Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
while(!driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui-datepicker-title'] [class='ui-datepicker-month']")).getText().contains("October"))
{
// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all']/span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e']")).click();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui-datepicker-title'] [class='ui-datepicker-month']")).getText());
}
List<WebElement> dates= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr//td"));
int count= dates.size();
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
String txt = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr//td")).get(i).getText();
if(txt.equalsIgnoreCase("28"))
{
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr//td")).get(i).click();
System.out.println(txt);
break;
}
}
// Return Date  Selection
Thread.sleep(3000); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_view_date2']")).click();
while(!driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui-datepicker-title'] [class='ui-datepicker-month']")).getText().contains("October"))
{
// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all']/span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e']")).click();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui-datepicker-title'] [class='ui-datepicker-month']")).getText());
}
List<WebElement> MDates= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr//td"));
int Mcount= dates.size();
for(int i=0; i<Mcount; i++)
{
String txt = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr//td")).get(i).getText();
if(txt.equalsIgnoreCase("31"))
{
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tr//td")).get(i).click();
System.out.println(txt);
break;
}
}
//Select Passengers
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='divpaxinfo']")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
WebElement Adults = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_Adult']")); Select adultsdrp = new Select(Adults);
adultsdrp.selectByValue("2");
WebElement childs = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_Child']"));
Select childsdrp = new Select(childs);
childsdrp.selectByValue("2");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='divpaxinfo']")).click();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='divpaxinfo']")).getText());
//Static Currency Dropdown
WebElement Currency =  driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_DropDownListCurrency"));
Select currencydrp = new Select(Currency);
currencydrp.selectByValue("USD"); Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_DropDownListCurrency")).getAttribute("value"), "USD"); System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_DropDownListCurrency")).getAttribute("value"));
}
}
```